# Converting C Code to Assembly (Motorola 68k)

Tags: assembly

I'm trying to convert these variables to assembly viable code:

```
char s[] = “TA”;
short int x;
int e = 99;
```

I did this with the int e:

```
CLR.B   D1   e = 99; // which compiles
```

I'm not sure how to go about doing arrays, or short int's?
I know for Arrays I can do something like:

`ARRAY:     DC.W    "Value here"` 
but does that work for a character array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this nice link](http://dev-docs.atariforge.org/files/Asm_Lang_Prog_68K_Family.pdf) on 68000 assembler.  It even has exercises for the user.  I compiled this entire answer completely from the given link.

```
BUFFER: DC.B 'TA'
```

handles your string (note bytes, not words as you have) and

```
BUFFER2: DS.W 1
```

Handles a single (1 value), short allocation.

Note that:

```
BUFFER3: DC.L 99
```

would be how to define your `e` variable assignment to 99.

Comment: Thanks, is this the only way to do this though? Is my Way of defining 'e' wrong per say, or is this just a more effiecient way to do it on the Motorolla 68000

Comment: Your way is basically clearing a byte (to zero) and feeding back to to memory at run time (and does not appear to set it to 99).  The way I have it, (if I am correct and I am by no means a 68k expert) is to have the assembler tell the system that this memory is cleared for you.  This should clear it for you at startup before you even run code.  But... it probably depends a whole bunch on what system you are assembling against.  I'd read that manual I sent you closely to learn more as it really appears to be very well written.